# codeigniter - .htaccess redirection issue in http to https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

When I try to redirect with or without www (example.com, www.example.com) To https://www.example.com, I am getting "The page isn’t redirecting properly" Error Message.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

I tied below code also

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But when i try to redirect without www To https://www.example.com is working fine.

I need to redirect with or without www example.com To https://www.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is redirecting (with or without www).example.com to https://www.example.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(example.com)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```